# How can I use an Eclipse project having only the compiled (bin) directory?

Tags: java, eclipse, decompiling

I accidentally backed up only the /bin/ section of my Eclipse Java project, containing only the compiled .class files, everything else sadly got wiped. Is there any way to make them back into a normal Java project? If not, is there a way to decompile them so that I can simply recreate the project in Eclipse and copy+paste all the code in the right places?

Comment: I would suggest having a look at Java Decompiler(http://jd.benow.ca/).

Comment: Thank you, this allowed me to get majority of my code back.

Comment: Glad I could help and that you were able to at least salvage some of your work.